# Place table inside a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, output-formatting

I have a simple graph:

```
mygraph = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}]
```

and a simple table:

```
mytable = 
 TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
  TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]
```

and I would like to place the table adjacent one of the vertices in the graph.

I've tried `Epilog`, and converting `mytable` into some form of graphic to `Show[]` them overlapped, without success.

As mentioned:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1},
 Epilog -> 
  Graphics@TableForm[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
    TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3"}, {"c1", "c2"}}]]
```

(and obvious variations thereon) fails.

Comment: Can you show your attempt with `Epilog`?

Comment: Perhaps `GraphicsGrid` could help, since it automatically outputs a `Graphics` object? Something along the lines of `GraphicsGrid[
 {{"", "c1", "c2"}, {"r1", a, b}, {"r2", c, d}, {"r3", e, f}},
 Dividers -> {{False, True}, {False, True}}]`

Comment: `Graphics` is not a graphics primitive, and won't convert something to graphics. It can't be used in `Epilog`. Use either `Inset` or `Text` (and set the coordinates too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Epilog -> Inset[...]`:

```
Graph[mygraph,  ImagePadding -> {{100, 10}, {40, 10}},
 Epilog -> Inset[mytable, PropertyValue[{mygraph, 1}, VertexCoordinates], Right, Scaled[1]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can label a specific vertex using `Labeled` or `VertexLabels -> ...`:

```
Graph[mygraph,  VertexLabels -> {_ :> "Name", 1 -> Placed[mytable, Before]}]
```

or

```
Graph[{Labeled[3, mytable, Before], 2, 3}, EdgeList@mygraph, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much.  (Accept)